# Array wraparound going to null

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2d char array, of which I am trying to retrieve the value of an opposite side while on the edge. Instead of retrieving that value, it keeps returning with null. Can't make heads or tails of what the problem is. Here is the code I traced the problem to.

````
        int xO = x; int yO = y;
        //reassigns to opposite side of array
        if ((x == 0) && (xM == - 1)) { xM = mapSize - 1; }
        if ((x == mapSize - 1) && (xM == 1)) { xM = 0 - (mapSize - 1); }
        if ((y == 0) && (yM == - 1)) { yM = mapSize - 1; }
        if ((y == mapSize - 1) && (yM == 1)) { yM = 0 - (mapSize - 1);
        }
        //Checks 9 chars around and assigns any found characters
        if (mapPlates[x + xM][y + yM] == 0) {
            std::cout << "//" + std::to_string(x + xM) + ", " + std::to_string(yM + y) + "; " + std::to_string(mapPlates[x + xM][y + yM]) + "//";
        }
        if (mapPlates[x + xM][y + yM] =! "%") {
            remaining--;
            mapPlates[xO][yO] = mapPlates[x + xM][y + yM];
            std::cout << "{assigned " + std::to_string(mapPlates[xO][yO]) + " }";
        }

        return remaining;
    }

Snippet of output(only returns values == null)(should be returning '%'):

```//14, 49; 0////14, 0; 0////14, 1; 0////19, 49; 0////20, 49; 0////19, 0;
````

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Also [edit] and format your question properly, especially the output snippet which is totally messed up and unreadable (what are all those `////`?). Read this: [ask]

Comment: The output snippet is still a mess. Please edit, otherwise your question will be downvoted/closed soon. Also read the first comment closely and edit accordingly.

Comment: `mapPlates[x + xM][y + yM] =! "%"` is an assignment and equivalent to `mapPlates[x + xM][y + yM] = 0` (A decent compiler would warn you about this.) You meant `!= '%'`. Voting to close as typo.